# How can I use undo | redo or in google cloud firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-realtime-api

I am trying to migrate app from Google Realtime to Google Cloud Firestore as following reason.

> Important dates to note
>
> As of November 28, 2017, Realtime API is no longer available for new
>   projects. Google API Console projects which accessed Realtime API
>   prior to November 28, 2017 (including your projects listed above) will
>   continue to function normally until December 11, 2018.
>
> On December 11, 2018, Realtime API documents will be made read-only,
>   and attempts to modify document contents using the API will fail.
>
> On January 15, 2019, Realtime API will be shut down, but an endpoint
>   to export document contents will remain available.

Realtime API supports versioning for document.
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/migration

```
function retrieveRealtimeJson(docId, revision) {
  gapi.client.drive.realtime.get({
      'fileId': docId,
      'revision': revision   // =====> can get previous version of doc
    }).then(function(response) {
      return response.data;
    });
  return null;
}
```

Also Realtime API supports UNDO and REDO.
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/undo

```
if (model.canUndo) {
  model.undo();
} else {
  console.log("No events to undo.");
}
```

Is there a equivalent function of **undo and redo** or **fetching revision** in Google Cloud Firestore ?

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud Firestore does not have built-in versioning of documents.

If your use-case requires versioning, you will have to build that on top of the Firestore API yourself.

For example, you could make the versioned content a subcollection of each document, so that each version is a separate document in a subcollection: `/documents/document1/versions/1`, `/documents/document1/versions/2`, etc.

Comment: This would be a good use of Cloud Functions.  `event.data.previous.data() ` could be saved to a `versions` sub-collection, along with a timestamp to order the documents by revision.

Comment: Ooh... that's indeed an interesting use-case. I never thought of that!

Comment: I'm full of useless ideas.  Sometimes, I come up with a good one :)

Comment: Versioning (using Cloud Functions) could be good entry for the Solutions section of the documentation.  It solves an issue that I have with tracking updates by Admins to user settings.